# How do I set my scrollbar to display only in one div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, height, overflow

I am working on an angular SPA that is supposed to generate several searchable lists of data within separate tabs. I have organized them in the following manner:

```
    <body>
      <tabset>
        <tab>
          <div class="listedData">
            <ul>
              <li class="searchBar"></li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="dataDetails">
          </div>
        </tab>
        //... other tabs
      </tabset>    
    </body>
```

I would like the page to take up the height of the screen and, since the list of data will probably take up more than that I would like to set up a scroll bar *only* inside the `<ul>` (preferably skipping the first element - `searchBar`) but I can live with that.

For that purpose, I have defined my css as follows:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.listedData {
  ul {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 95%;
    overflow-y: auto;  
  }
}
```

But I am not getting the desired results, i e the list simply stretches out of screen to encase all the elements and I can scroll the entire page to see them. I have tried to set the `height` property for all the tags in the chain (`<tabset>` , `<tab>` and `<div>`) but it made no difference. Is there a way to accomplish what I have in mind through pure css or am I forced to  do it through javascript?

Comment: Check your div.listedData height with your browser's developer tool. You may have to set it.

Comment: I tried setting its height and the height of every intermediate tag but it still made no difference.

Comment: Take a look if you have scss. If you have only pure css, you can't nest the styles like you did.

Answer (score 0):

To set percentual value on ul, you'll have to set the wrapping div's height.

if you want to have your scrollbar, you can use styles like below. I changed the html and some values for the example to be clearer.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.listedData {
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;

}

.listedData ul {
  width: 20%;
  max-height: 70%;
  overflow-y: auto;  
}
```

```html
<body>
      <tabset>
        <tab>
          <div class="listedData">
            <ul>
              <li class="searchBar">content li 1</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 2</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 3</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 4</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 5</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 6</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 7</li>
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 8</li>              
              <li ng-repeat="iterateHere"> content li 9</li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="dataDetails">
          </div>
        </tab>
        //... other tabs
      </tabset>    
    </body>
```

Obs: for the scroll to skip only the seachbar it will be a lot more difficult. I suggest putting an input before the ul element. It will have better usability.

Comment: This is the behavior I was expecting too, but explicitly setting the height property on that div (`.listedData`) still didn't change anything. I tried it again right now, just in case and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JovanDamjanovic maybe trying to change the display property of your ul. (that "float: left" may also be a suspect of strange behavior)

Comment: Tried playing around with display but to no avail. The float is there to position it to the left of the `details` div and from my perspective it shouldn't impact the height...